# No Value Given for one or more required parameters

Tags: vb.net, sql-update

I'm trying to get this update command to work. I have a table in access that has two fields, and I'm just trying to update the second one. I have code like this already in my program and it worked - I can't figure out why this code doesn't work:

```
Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Try
        Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=BuddyMatching.accdb;Persist Security Info=False")
        Dim cmd1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update Priorities set priorityDesc = '" & ComboBox12.Text & "' where priorityNum =1", conn)
        Dim cmd2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update Priorities set priorityDesc = '" & ComboBox13.Text & "' where priorityNum =2", conn)
        Dim cmd3 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update Priorities set priorityDesc = '" & ComboBox14.Text & "' where priorityNum =3", conn)

        conn.Open()
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Every time I run this code, I get "No value given for one or more required parameters" returned via the MsgBox. My ComboBoxes are not inputting null values, so that's not it. Hopefully another set of eyes will spot the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using parametrized queries. That said does table named `Priorities` has fields named exactly `priorityDesc` and `priorityNum` ? Also what are the values supplied by comboboxes - can you provide examples?

Comment: you could use a breakpoint and find out which one is causing the exception

Comment: Things to check: 1) Double-check the spelling in your database for the  `priorityDesc` and `priorityNum` columns. 2) Make sure `priorityNum` is actually a numeric data type (int, number, numeric, etc.). I'm thinking that  either something is misspelled or you need single quotes around your `priorityNum` values.

Comment: I've made sure that the datatype is an integer, and that the field names are exactly as I've coded them. For the combobox values, there are only 3 valid ones; "School" , "LOB", and "Location". cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery() is the one throwing the exception